# rename or disable oracle foreign key to delete parent table

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key, unique-key

I have a table that has a PK that is used as a FK in multiple tables.  I have to drop the parent table because of an issue I'm having but it will not let me because of the FK.  I try and drop the PK and UK from the parent table and it errors out saying there are tables still using them.  I even disabled the FK on multiple tables and tried deleting the table, PK and UK and it still says that there are tables tied to them.

Is there any way I can drop a parent table in oracle and then recreate it with the exact same PK and UK without having to delete the FK from multiple tables?

Thank you

Comment: You disabled the FKs on the child tables?

Comment: Why do you want to recreate a table? You can make any changes using `alter table` command.

Comment: I renamed it because I wanted to make sure I didn't lose the data.  I should have taken a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can drop a parent table in oracle and then recreate
>   it with the exact same PK and UK without having to delete the FK from
>   multiple tables?

Yes, you use DBMS_REDEFINITION.  You can use DBMS_REDEFINITION to do whatever you need to do as part of this "fix": rebuild the table, add/remove columns, reorder columns, add partitioning, etc.

The only thing you *can't* really do is change the structure of the primary key. 
But, if you were doing that, you'd have the drop all the FKs anyway.

Here's a quick example:

```
-- Create a parent / child relationship with data....
CREATE TABLE matt_parent
(
  id       NUMBER,
  value1   VARCHAR2 (30),
  CONSTRAINT matt_parent_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE matt_child
(
  id          NUMBER,
  parent_id   NUMBER,
  value2      VARCHAR2 (30),
  CONSTRAINT matt_child_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT matt_child_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES matt_parent (id)
);

insert into matt_parent values (1, 'XXX');

insert into matt_child values ( 100, 1, 'YYY');

COMMIT;

-- These next few SQLs use online redefinition to change the parent table (adding a column and adding partitioning)
-- First, have Oracle check whether redefinition is going to work
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE('apps','matt_parent',
      DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
END;
/

-- Second, create our rebuilt table.  It eventually replaces our current table.
CREATE TABLE apps.matt_parent_redef
  ( 
  id       NUMBER,
  date1    DATE,
  value1   VARCHAR2 (30)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (date1)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL (1,'DAY')) ( partition parent_old values less than (to_date('01-JAN-2000','DD-MON-YYYY') ));
;

-- Run this if you need to start over...
--BEGIN
--DBMS_REDEFINITION.ABORT_REDEF_TABLE (
--   uname   => 'apps',
--   orig_table => 'matt_parent',
--   int_table   => 'matt_parent_redef');
--END;


-- Third, tell Oracle to start the redefinition process.  Can take long -- copies all the data into our new table
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('apps', 'matt_parent','matt_parent_redef',
       'id, sysdate date1, value1',
        dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid);
END;
/

-- Fourth, tell Oracle to copy dependent objects like PK constaints, FKs, grants, etc
DECLARE
num_errors PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS('apps', 'matt_parent','matt_parent_redef',
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_ORIG_PARAMS, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, num_errors);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Copy depenedent objects: num_errors = ' || num_errors);   
END;


-- Fifth, query to make sure there were no problems.  This should return no rows
select * from         DBA_REDEFINITION_ERRORS where base_table_name = 'MATT_PARENT';


-- Sixth, tell Oracle we're finished.  This *briefly* locks the table as the switch is accomplished.
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE('apps', 'matt_parent', 'matt_parent_redef');
END;
/

-- Later, drop the redefinition version of the table.
DROP TABLE apps.matt_parent_redef CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

-- Try to delete some parent data, just to verify our FKs are still in force.
delete from matt_parent where id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew.  The issue with this is that I don't have full DBA permissions.  I ended up disabling constraints on all dependency tables and then used the table I renamed and make sure I had the correct primary and foreign keys.